# Homework: Java calculator dealing with dates -- Is my array correct?

Tags: java, date

I'm working on a Java assignment, where we take a date and do some calculations on it in various ways. Right now I'm working on a piece that will use my Array. Basically it's a list of the months by day. 0 for January 1st, 31 for Feburary 1, etc...

Does my array look correct based on these values?

Here's my array:

```
  private static int[] cumulDays = {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};
```

Java Assignment Doc for reference: 
http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs161/assignments/PA2/doc/MyUTC.html#cumulDays

> cumulDays 
>   private static int[]
>   cumulDays number of days from the
>   beginning of the year to the beginning
>   of a month (0 for Jan, 31 for Feb,
>   ...). You will want to initialize
>   this.

Comment: You really can't use a calculator and a calendar to double-check this yourself?  Even giving you the benefit of a doubt that's at most 2 minutes of work.

Comment: This is not correct for leap years, of course.

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to ask homework questions here. Do the work.

Comment: I did check, but I wanted a second opinion. And yes I have asked homework questions on here before without issue. And I DID the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array values are correct. However, as the assignment Javadoc state, "you will want to initialize this"; you need to take into account [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). However, since you basically don't have that many array possibilities, you could simply create two static arrays

```
private static int[] CUMUL_DAYS = {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};
private static int[] CUMUL_DAYS_LEAP = {0,31,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335};
```

and depending on if the year is leap or not, return one of the static array

Comment: There's a leap year function that I wrote, when I do the array I'll just increment the array above index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  His last value is 334 because the zero is given for January 1st (as zero days have passed at that point).  You may consider entering a cumulative entry of value 365 at 12 for December 31st, but it depends on how you are manipulating your date-data.

Depending on the specifications of your homework, it may be more beneficial to use Java's built in [Date class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: To address your second point, from the homework link provided: **You may not use the Java Date, Calendar or any other Java classes dealing with Dates and times.**.